# Kotlin Android Apollo client is not generating Schema classes

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client

I am developing an Android application. In my application, I am using Apollo client to consume GraphQL API. When I build the project, it is not generating the classes based on the schema.json file. This is what I have done so far.

This is my app grandle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.memento"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    compileOnly 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'
    testCompileOnly 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'
}
```

This is my project grandle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:1.1.3'
        classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have the schema.json and this is the project structure

[image]

When I build the project, the classes are generated in this folder

[image]

But I cannot call those classes in my code. It is showing this error.

[image]

How can I use those classes in my code?

Comment: where you able to figure this out. I am seeing the same thing with Kotlin models ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make query in a file with `.graphql` extension on same location as your Schema.json is. Then rebuild your project and it will generate classes.